# HQL/SQL 'NOT AT ALL IN' clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

When I use the Hibernate Query (if you only know SQL don't leave yet!): `FROM Entity e WHERE 'USA' NOT IN e.addresses` it returns all entities that have ***AN*** address outside of the USA, but I want to only get the entities that have ***NONE*** of their addresses in the USA (in this example).

How do I do this in HQL (probably similar issue with SQL just slightly different syntax, if you could explain it to me how it works in SQL I will most likely understand it as well only never used WHERE 'item' NOT IN (array) in SQL).

Added: please note that e.addresses is an array

Comment: I haven't done much HQL but I hope my answer works for you after some manipulations for HQL (I have assumed that the PK for the Entity table is e

Comment: Could you set your `showSQL` in hibernate config to true and paste what does the generated SQL look like? I don't have a test environment to check right now, but I belive it should have worked as you expected, and my first try at guessing what sql your query would have generated also gives the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a One to Many Relationship between your entities and addresses. What you need to do is to first find entities with address inside USA and then subtract the same (using NOT IN maybe?) from the total number of entities.

If you want help with the actual query, you can post your table structure here

```
FROM Entity e2
WHERE e2.id NOT IN ( e1.id FROM Entity e as e1 WHERE 'USA' IN e1.addresses)
```

Comment: Good solution :) thnx!